# Rails 4 after_save previous_changes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, awesome-nested-set

I have an after_save callback on a model, and I'm calling previous_changes to see if an attribute (is_complete) changed. Even when the attribute changes, previous_changes returns an empty hash.

Here's the callback:

```
after_save do |record|
  puts "********************"
  puts record.previous_changes.to_s
  puts record.is_complete
  puts "********************"
end
```

and here's what I get in the log:

```
********************
{}
true
********************
********************
{}
false
********************
```

If the value of is_complete changed from true to false, it should be in the previous_changes hash.  The update is being done via a normal save! and I'm not reloading the object.

--- **UPDATE** ---

I hadn't considered this when I posted the question, but my model uses the awesome_nested_set gem, and it appears that this is reloading the object or somehow interfering with the after_save callback.  When I comment out acts_as_nested_set, the callback appears to be working fine.

--- **UPDATE 2** ---

Fixed this with an around_save callback, which first determines if the attribute changed, then yields, then does the stuff I need it to do after the change has been made in the DB.  The working solution looks like this:

```
around_save do |record, block|
  is_complete_changed = true if record.is_complete_changed?
  block.call
  if is_complete_changed
    ** do stuff **
  end
end
```

Comment: Known bug - https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/issues/276

Answer (score 6):

According to [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96cc2e8335ab3e4166e476415753125864d88196/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb) source code

From line 274

```
 def changes_applied # :doc:
    @previously_changed = changes
    @changed_attributes = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
 end
```

So the changes will be set to `@previously_changed` after `changes_applied` was called, and `changes_apply` was call when `save` was called, that means `AFTER DOING PERSISTENT WORK` (line 42)

In summary, `previous_changes` only has values when the record was actually saved to persistent storage (DB)

So in your callback, you may use `record.changed_attributes`, and outside use `previously_changed`, it will work fine!

Answer (score 1):

I did not dig super deep, but from the first sight into [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb) you [can see](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb#L162), that in method `previous_changes`:

```
def previous_changes
  @previously_changed ||= ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
end
```

`@previously_changed` is not defined anywhere ([except for here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb#L215), which uses the `changes` method I speak of below), thus you get the empty (nice and with indifferent access though :D) hash all the time.

What you really want to use, is a [`changes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb#L152) method:

```
def changes
  ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess[changed.map { |attr| [attr, attribute_change(attr)] }]
end
```

It would return your expected

```
#=> {"is_complete"=>[true, false]}
```

Comment: apparently, the awesome_nested_set gem is interfering with the callback; presumably by somehow reloading the object before the callback is fired (see my update above). not sure if there's a way to work around this. thanks for your help. -john

Comment: permanent link to `changes` method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2b584f165bc919c5e698e52d84c582a2f5f22b35/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb#L152